# Axios returns 401 Error writing to Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I currently have a scheduled function running as a cloud function that uses Axios to write to the Realtime Database in Firebase. However, I continue to receive the error:

> 'Request failed with status code 401'

Which seems to be an authorization error. I am using Axios with authorization using a legacy token, specifically the secret for the database.

Am I using authorization wrong here or is there another way to do this? The issue I have is using authorization for access specifically in a scheduled function.

**App.js**

```
exports.callTo = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").onRun((context) => {
  let searchTrends;
  googleTrends.dailyTrends({
    trendDate: new Date("2021-10-20"),
    geo: "US",
  }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      functions.logger.error(err);
    } else {
      searchTrends = JSON.parse(res).default.trendingSearchesDays
          .trendingSearches;
      const query = searchTrends[2] + " since:2021-10-20";

      return axios.put("https://testtter-c0e48-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/searchTrends.json?auth=<account_secret>", {trends: searchTrends})
          .then((res) => {
            functions.logger.log("Result: " + res);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            functions.logger.log("Error: " + error);
          });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: CORS related maybe

Comment: How do you get account_secret?

Comment: @atx Under Project Settings -> Service Accounts -> Legacy Credentials -> Database Secret.

Comment: Simplify and isolate the problem: do you have the same problem if you run a local Node.js script with the same code? Do you still have the problem if you try to read data instead of writing it? Do you still have the problem if you don't use Axis, but something like Postman?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Same issue if I am reading data from the database as the user accessing has to be authenticated as per the database rules. When I used Postman I receive the error 'Could Not Parse Auth Token'.